# How can I completely remove the Swarm Desktop App and reinstall it?

Tags: swarm

I would like to perform a fresh installation of the Swarm Desktop app.

I tried deleting the folder located at `/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Swarm Desktop/` and Swarm Desktop App from the Applications folder (MacOS) but the RPC URL remained the same after reinstalling the app.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting files from folder location you should also delete local storage in the browser. Go to dev console, select Application tab and delete the key json-rpc-prodiver in Local storage.

[image]